# pre-commit for local hook gives error: "unrecognized arguments: .pre-commit-config.yaml"

Tags: continuous-integration, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have the following repo in `pre-commit` file `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: check_pip
        name: Check pip file
        description: This hook checks if requirements-dev.txt is up to date.
        language: system
        entry: python -m scripts.check_pip_requirements
        args: ["--compare"]
```

But it keeps giving me the error:

> error: unrecognized arguments: .pre-commit-config.yaml

As it passes the filename as an argument to my python script. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to clean up your example a little bit -- and use `files` to only run when the necessary files change:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: check_pip
        name: Check pip file
        description: This hook checks if requirements-dev.txt is up to date.
        language: system
        entry: python -m scripts.check_pip_requirements --compare
        files: ^requirements-dev.txt$
        pass_filenames: false
```

note that I did a couple things:

- `args` doesn't really make sense for `local` hooks, you can just put that in `entry`
- `pass_filenames` (as you did) -- `pre-commit` is a framework based on passing filenames to executables, but you can turn that off
- `files`: this will make it so the hook only gets triggered if `requirements-dev.txt` changes

alternatively (if you expect changes outside `requirements-dev.txt` to need to run this hook) you can drop `files` and use [`always_run: true`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-always_run)

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit

Comment: The original script creates `requirements-dev.txt` from a conda `environment.yml`. So would it make sense to put: `^environment.yml$` in `files`? Because we want to check if the users requirements is updated when `environment.yml` changes, which is leading.

Answer (score 2):

I spent quite some time figuring out what caused this and how to solve this. It's not documented well, eventually I fixed it by trial and error. We have to use `pass_filenames: false` in our hook:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: check_pip
        name: Check pip file
        description: This hook checks if requirements-dev.txt is up to date.
        language: system
        entry: python -m scripts.check_pip_requirements
        pass_filenames: false
        args: ["--compare"]
```

Comment: if you could improve the docs that'd be great -- [`pass_filenames`](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-pass_filenames), [arguments patterns in hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks)

Comment: Will definitely do, thanks for the updated answer and explanation.

Comment: Submitted the [PR](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit.com/pull/401) @AnthonySottile